# Does all eSATA enclosures use their own Controller Card?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sata, esata, enclosures

I regularly have to test multiple hard drives on a daily basis using the manufacturers provided tools. Often I come across older drives that do not work so well with USB3 docking stations, sometimes you even get false positives.

So I'm thinking eSATA is the way forward since it'll use my onboard Intel chipset which I have more success with. The problem I'm finding is that I can't seem to find a 2m eSATA to 22pin Sata/Power cable, they all seem to be around the 45cm to 55cm mark. Which won't even reach the height of my desk. So, then I got thinking about using an enclosure or dock that has an eSATA port but then I noticed that some enclosures with multiple bays offer RAID JOBD 0/1/10 with eSATA, which would imply there is a controller before onboard controller.

Question(s):

- Do docking or multiple eSATA bay enclosures have their own SATA controller when using eSATA? if, not, then how do they handle the raid?
- Is there any particular reason why I can't find a 2meter 7pin eSATA to 22pin (7+15 duo) SATA Cable?

Comment: "Is there any particular reason why I can't a 2meter 7pin eSATA to 22pin SATA?" - This question is not clear.  Please edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: @Ramhound, missing word was 'find', I've corrected the question. Thanks.